# Groovy MetaClass "No such property" when it's listed as a possible solution

Tags: groovy, metaprogramming

I have some code which looks like this:

```
propertyLabels.each { label ->
    LaboratoryResultBuilder.metaClass."$label" = null
}
```

which I use to dynamically add properties to my class, e.g., as documented [here](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/#_properties_2). What's unexpected is that the property names don't always work. When I do this:

```
lrBuilder["Mass"] = lrv //fails
```

I get the exception:

```
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: Mass for class: LaboratoryResultBuilder
Possible solutions: Mass, class, name
Error |     at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.unwrap(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:53)
Error |     at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoMetaMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:253)
Error |     at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.call(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:71)
Error |     at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
Error |     at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
Error |     at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:133)
```

which I find entirely unhelpful: the "missing" property is suggested as available. Looking at this:

```
    println LaboratoryResultBuilder.metaClass.properties.collect {MetaProperty mp -> mp.name}
    println LaboratoryResultBuilder.metaClass.methods.collect {MetaMethod mm->mm.name}
```

I can see my property `Mass` in the property list and `getMass` and `setMass` in the method list. If I try to set the property with one of these:

```
lrBuilder["mass"] = lrv //works
lrBuilder.setMass(lrv) //works
lrBuilder.setProperty("Mass",lrv) // fails with same error
```

so it appears like Groovy is doing some property name manipulation which is not 1-to-1. It looks like it wants to use camel case dynamic method names. My question is how can I reliably set values based on the (original) label I used to create the property? The best I've come up with so far looks like this:

```
String getMangledPropertyName(String prop){
    if(prop.length() > 1 && Character.isUpperCase(prop.charAt(1))){
        return prop
    } else {
        return prop.substring(0, 1).toLowerCase() + prop.substring(1);
    }
}
```

and then

```
lrBuilder[getMangledPropertyName("Mass")] = lrv //works
```

but that's just based on guesswork, I can't find documentation anywhere.

I'm using this groovy 2.4.5 (in grails 2.5.5).

edit: a self contained script which demonstrates the problem:

```
package testpackage
println "Groovy version: " +GroovySystem.version

class TestClass implements Serializable {
    static void addProperties(ArrayList propertyLabels) {
        propertyLabels.each { label ->
            TestClass.metaClass."$label" = null
        }
        println TestClass.metaClass.properties.collect {MetaProperty mp -> mp.name}
        println TestClass.metaClass.methods.collect {MetaMethod mm->mm.name}
    }
}

def names = ["Capitalized","UPPER","lower"]

TestClass.addProperties(names)
//TestClass.metaClass.myArray = []

def tc = new TestClass()

tc.metaClass.myArray = []
names.each {
    println "trying name: "+it
    try {
        tc[it] = 123
    } catch(Exception e){
        println e.message
    }
}
```

yields output:

```
Groovy version: 2.4.5
[class, UPPER, lower, Capitalized]
[setLower, setCapitalized, getUPPER, getLower, setUPPER, getCapitalized, equals, getClass, hashCode, notify, notifyAll, toString, wait, wait, wait, addProperties, getMetaClass, getProperty, invokeMethod, setMetaClass, setProperty]
trying name: Capitalized
No such property: Capitalized for class: testpackage.TestClass
Possible solutions: Capitalized
trying name: UPPER
trying name: lower
```

Note: it works if I don't assign the `myArray` value to an instance of `TestClass`, so the problem seems specific to that. Should I not be referencing `metaClass` on an instance?

Comment: do you have a short example script that we can run that exhibits the issue?

Comment: @tim_yates here you go. took me a while to figure out how to reproduce...

Comment: This is a really good and well-researched question.  I'm surprised it does not have more views/upvotes/answers.